# Can I exclude a number or subrange of numbers inside a range of random numbers in modern C++?

Tags: c++, c++11, random, c++17

I have:

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> probability(0, 100);
```

I want to exclude some numbers in this range of probabilities.
Example 1: Let's say, I want to generate a random number between 0 and 100, but this number can never be 4.
Example 2: Let's say, I want to generate a random number between 0 and 100, but this number can never be any number between 4 and 7.

I wonder if it is possible to achieve in modern C++ without using `std::rand`?

Comment: You could use a [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) and set the values you do not want to zero probability.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you want to stay with a `uniform_int_distribution` you can do it manually like this:

> Example1: Let's say, I want to generate a random number in between 0 and 100, but this number can never be 4.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,99);
auto temp = distribution(mt);
auto random_number = (temp < 4) ? temp : temp + 1;
```

> Example2: Let's say, I want to generate a random number in between 0 and 100, but this number can never be any number between 4 and 7.

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(0,96);
auto temp = distribution(mt);
auto random_number = (temp < 4) ? temp : temp + 4;
```

This could be generalize to write a function `random_int_between_excluding(int first, int last, std::vector<int> exclude)`, though at some point it will be simpler to follow NathanOlivers suggestion and use a [`std::discrete_distribution`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/discrete_distribution) instead.

Comment: Well done for taking the time to write out the solution (unlike me who didn't want to face the complexity of unpicking "between 4 and 7"). Have an upvote! (Personally I think `probability` is a misnomer but that's a small point.)

Comment: This is a really neat way to go about it, but `int` does not have wraparound behavior, so there is a small risk of Undefined Behavior here. You should be doing the increment on a `unsigned int` instead

Answer (score 5):

> Example2: Let's say, I want to generate a random number in between 0
> and 100, but this number can never be any number between 4 and 7.

This is what [std::piecewise_constant_distribution](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/piecewise_constant_distribution) is for.

```cpp
    std::vector<int> i{0,  4, 8, 101};
    std::vector<int> w{ 4,  0,  93};
    std::piecewise_constant_distribution<> d(i.begin(), i.end(), w.begin());
```

[Live demo](https://godbolt.org/z/voYqT6anW)

Comment: Note that this is a continuous (floating point) distribution. You need the `101.0` upper limit so that the range `100.0, 101.0` can be rounded down to 100.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to miss out 4 say, then a very good way (which doesn't compromise any statistical properties of the generator), is to draw in the half-open interval [0, 99) then add 1 if the number is 4 or greater.

You do something similar to omit numbers in a range.

This method is a surprisingly good way of modelling the *quantile* function associated with the desired probability distribution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a filter of arbitrary complexity on uniform distribution:

```
template<typename D, typename G, typename F>
auto sample(D &distribution, G &generator, F const &filter)
{
    while(true)
    {
        auto const value = distribution(generator);
        if(filter(value))
            return value;
    }
}
```

Your example case transforms into the following

```
std::random_device rd;
std::mt19937 mt(rd());
std::uniform_int_distribution<int> probability(0, 100);

auto const filter = +[](int n) {return n < 4 || n > 7;}
int const i = sample(probability, mt, filter);
```

You have to keep in mind that this kind of filtering comes at a cost.

Let `N` be the number of distinct values the distribution returns, `F` - the number of these values filtered out; then, if you need to sample `S` values, you have to sample and filter `S * N / (N - F)` values at average. It's okay if F is small compared to N, but horribly inefficient when F approaches N. In your case, `N = 100`, `F = 4`, and `N / (N - F) = 1.04166...`

If you care prefer readability and simplicity, that's your choice. Otherwise, if you need performance, you'd better try out piecewise distributions or mess with the value range manually.

Answer (score 0):

There is an option to do it manually within a reasonable range of numbers..., create a look up table and exclude the numbers that are invalid:

```
 static int rand_pool[]{1,2,3,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23}; //no number 4
    srand((int)time(0));
        int random_number = rand_pool[rand() % 22];
```

Comment: Also with unreasonable range of numbers. You can just generate this table programmatically.

Comment: @pptaszni: Using metaprogramming / constexpr programming.

Comment: this is a huge step back, because `rand() % 22` is not actually uniform

Comment: suppose `RAND_MAX % 22` would be eg `11` then the first half has higher probability than the last half

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number - there are 22 values in that particular array and rand()% 22 should generate a number within those 22 values. %23 will generate a compiler warning.

Comment: `rand() %22` does result in a number in `[0,21)`, but even if `rand()` is uniformly distrubuted, `rand()%n` generally is not. stl mentions the reason in this talk: https://channel9.msdn.com/Events/GoingNative/2013/rand-Considered-Harmful. I think the talk is a bit exxagerated, but the facts are all good to know